# How to keep delated items in a array from returning after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript

I made a delete function for a table; it works but when the page is refreshed the items return. The project can be found on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/kiva-gordon/pen/ExmWebm?editors=1010)

```
const showExpenses = () => {

  const table = document.getElementById('expenseTable');

    table.innerHTML = '';
  
  for(let i = 0; i < expenses.length; i++){
        expenseTable.innerHTML += `
            <tr >
                <td class="expItem">${expenses[i].name}</td>
                <td class="expItem">${expenses[i].date}</td>
                <td class="expItem">$${expenses[i].amount}</td>
                <td><a class="deleteButton" href="#" data-id="${expenses[i].id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        `;
    }
}

//Remove buttom
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('click', '.deleteButton', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent the href default 
     // if you need to access the id...
     let deleteID = $(this).data('id');
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   })
})
```

Comment: Save the array in `localStorage` and reload it when refreshing.

Comment: @Barmar I have it saved on line 24 actually

Comment: Then it should work. It might not work in codepen because of the sandboxing, but it should work in a real website.

Comment: Okay I'll try and see if it works outside codepen.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, the idea here is to save it to a type of storage that is persistent across a page reload. You can achieve this with `localStorage` as well as `sessionStorage`. In my example, I'll just show you how you can use localStorage, but you can read more about Session Storage here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

In your `$(document).ready(...)` is where you can load from local storage storage, and in your deleteButton onClick listener, you can save to storage. Local Storage uses key-value pairs to store and retrieve data, so whatever you call it when you save the data is also how you retrieve it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // As soon as jquery loads, load from storage
   // it will return null if nothing is stored yet
   deletedExpenses = localStorage.getItem("deletedExpenses");

   $('body').on('click', '.deleteButton', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent the href default 
     // if you need to access the id...
     let deleteID = $(this).data('id');
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();

     // You first have to load from storage the array of deleted items,
     var deletedArr = localStorage.getItem("deletedExpenses");

     // If you have nothing stored, this will return null,
     // And if that's the case, create new array
     if (!deletedArr)
       deletedArr = [];
     }
     // then push to this array another ID that got deleted
     deletedArr.push(deleteID);
     localStorage.setItem("deletedExpenses", deletedArr);
   })
})
```

Obviously this is not a complete example but it should lead you in the right direction.

Learn more about localStorage here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks I think I'm beginning to understand, I used your example but I got a error  saying "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')" does this mean my value is empty?

Comment: I updated my answer. Good catch. Since it's the first time loading from storage, it will be null so you cannot push to a variable that is null. You can check first if the value is null before pushing (and if it's null, set it to an empty array)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help and knowledge shared.